# scala + play on ubuntu

Tags: playframework, ubuntu-11.10, playframework-2.0

I've created a simply play application on my local machine (PC) and now I'd like to deploy to our internal server (clean Ubuntu 11 install). could you please point me to some tutorials (google search is quite unhelpful) how to set the server up and what the options are (eg tomcat, apache, etc.) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
play war yourappfolder -o yourappname.war --zip
```

Simply drop `yourappname.war` in the `WEB-APPS` directory of your tomcat server. App deployed!

Visit `localhost:8080/yourappname`

To install and run tomcat, check [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html) out